# TextView strip away top and bottom padding for easier aligning?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to align the top of a TextView (which will always be an integer greater than 0) and an ImageView.

Padding the top of the Imageview by `4dp` was very close, but it is an inexact solution.

The culprit is this:

[image: number padding]

Disregard the padding to the left. The padding above the number and below the number are frustrating. Is there any way to have the top and bottom completely wrap around the number? I suppose the issue will come from 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, etc. potentially having different upper limits, but is there a way to handle this? `android:includeFontPadding=false` gets rid of something of the padding, but it doesn't get rid of it all.

XML:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentsCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/commentsCountBubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_bubble"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
```

Wrapped in a standard LinearLayout.

**Edit:** Also note that the padding around the Imageview wraps the content completely (basically, there is no padding).

Comment: y cant u use drawableLeft?

Comment: What is drawableLeft?

Comment: Yes, all devices should be compatible.

Comment: watz the issue in ur device?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentsCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="4"/>
```

Comment: Wow. Mind blown. I had no idea this was even possible. Definitely fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually, this worked in the emulator, but doesn't work on my actual device.

Comment: which device u r using?

Comment: it must work in all devices... is ur app is compatible?

Comment: what is the issue in ur device?

Comment: It is a little bit above the number.

Comment: do u have same xml in other layout folders?

Comment: I only have 1 XML file that controls this.

Comment: There were no changes when I did that

Comment: i think ur image has transparent space.. crop the image without any transparent space....

Answer (score 0):

If your views are placed on `RelativeLayout` you can use that on your `TextView`:

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yourImageView"
```

Good luck.

Comment: This wouldn't work because it would align by the padding on top. Hence, the space issue on top would still exist.